# How to apply the SQL join syntax to legacy join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem when i refactoring the legacy join syntax to ANSI join syntax's, because most of the procedures  in our database is using the legacy join. this is the code I need to change it to use the SQL 'JOIN' syntax rather than the normal legacy join. can any one suggest me how it can be done?

```
    select 
          a.userkey, 
          a.username,
          c.monthd ,
          b.currencykey 
     from 
         #users a,
         #invoicedata b,
          #revdate c
     where 
         (a.userkey >= b.userkey or a.userkey <= b.userkey) 
          and b.idate between c.startdate and c.enddate
      group by 
           a.userkey,
           a.username,
           c.monthd,
           b.currencykey

       order by c.id,a.username,b.currencykey
```

Comment: The line `(a.userkey >= b.userkey or a.userkey <= b.userkey)` is redundant. There is no combination of `a.userkey` and `b.userkey` that would not satisfy this criteria. So you have created a cross join between `#users` and `#invoicedata`. Is this intentional?

Comment: No that was a actual query in the db. unfortunately i 'vent copied the whole select statement because it has some aggregate functions that's why  it using the group by clause, why we cant use the  relational operator in condition statement?

Comment: @Gareth: You are correct. Except if any of the columns is nullable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part `(a.userkey >= b.userkey or a.userkey <= b.userkey)` doesn't seem correct and you can't `order by` columns (at least without `agregate` functions) that aren't in the `group by`.

So, possibly something like this:

```
select 
      a.userkey, 
      a.username,
      c.monthd ,
      b.currencykey 
 from #users a
 inner join #invoicedata b on a.userkey = b.userkey
 inner join #revdate c on b.idate between c.startdate and c.enddate
 group by 
      a.userkey,
      a.username,
      c.monthd,
      b.currencykey
```

I've also replaced nested joins with inner joins but that wasn't necessary :)

---

On the other hand, you may want a cross join:

```
select 
      a.userkey, 
      a.username,
      c.monthd ,
      b.currencykey 
 from #users a
 cross join #invoicedata b
 inner join #revdate c on b.idate between c.startdate and c.enddate
 group by 
      a.userkey,
      a.username,
      c.monthd,
      b.currencykey
```

Comment: Thanks aF, It has some aggregate function to calculate the sum, but I'vent mention that because it was too long code. ignore the group by clause, why dont I put the relational operators in the condition statement?

Comment: The cross join should not have a predicate - it's not `cross join on...`, it's just cross join. Also, I delete comments that reference things that are no longer there... Hope that is OK.